# Show that the function $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb{R}^+$ with $f(x) = 2^{x+2}$ is injective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Show that the function $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb{R}^+$ with $f(x) = 2^{x+2}$ is injective.

I am trying to resolve a question about injective functions. I know that the rule for it to be injective is: Let $a,b ∈ \mathbb R$, show that if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a = b$.
$$
2^{a+2} = 2^{b+2}
$$
$$
2^{a}.2^{2} = 2^{b}.2^{2}
$$
$$
2^{a}.4 = 2^{b}.4
$$
$$\frac{2^{a}.4}{4} = \frac{2^{b}.4}{4}$$
$$
2^{a} = 2^{b}
$$
$$
a \log_2{1} = b \log_2{1}
$$
$$
a= b
$$

Is this right to say? I feel I have missed something, especially during the conversion from power to log.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are allowed to use logs, absolutely.

Comment: Alternative argument : the function is strictly increasing, hence is injective.

Comment: When you wrote that $a\log_21=b\log_21$, I suppose that you meant $a\log_22=b\log_22$.

Comment: @Randall Since the definition of $2^a$ for $a\in\Bbb R$ involves $\log$s, it would be difficult not to use them in any proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct, though it can be done in fewer steps.

$2^{a+2}=2^{b+2} \iff 1=2^{b-a} \iff  b-a = 0 \iff b=a$

Whether you should use $log$ to go from $1=2^{b-a}$ to $b-a = 0$ depends on the axioms, definitions and theorems you know in the context of this problem. If you somehow know $a^x = 1$ if and only if $x =0$ when $a$ is not $1, -1$ , then no need for $log$s. Otherwise it is okay to use it.